# Create list of from previous columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([[-1,1,2,3,4],[-2,5,6,7,8]],columns[["col_other","cola","colb","colc","cold"]])
```

[image]

given the table above how do I create a column `col_combine` that is a list of previous four columns
i.e., the values of two rows of `col_combine` are `[1,2,3,4]` and `[5,6,7,8]` respectively.

Comment: Check `df['col_combine'] = df.to_numpy().tolist()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sorry I modified the question a bit

Comment: No problem, in that case you can use `df.to_numpy()[:, -4:].tolist()`